# SSH access to specific LDAP group

Tags: ssh, ldap

I have created one openLDAP server and one client. Now the requirement is to only allow members of some specific LDAP group to do SSH on this client.

Client machine

i can see the LDAP group using 'getent group'

this is my /etc/pam.d/sshd file

```
%PAM-1.0
account    required     pam_access.so
auth       required     pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow 
file=/etc/openldap/sshgroups
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in 
the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

the content of file /etc/openldap/sshgroups:

```
root
centos
ldap-test-group
```

but all the LDAP users are able to login to the client machine.

what is wrong here?

Comment: If i want to restrict users i am able to do so using following this line "auth       required     pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=user sense=allow 
    file=/etc/openldap/sshusers". That means, the group are not restrcited using this way but the users.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a lot of hit and trial methods, I was able to get it using pam_access.so and access.conf.

Comment: This would be a very useful answer if you documented what did work, as opposed to simply saying "I did somethings involving these words" which does actually answer the question.  I'd change my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer didn't provide any specific information, I'll provide an example that I was able to come up with.  This assumes that you assign users to a unix group "mygroup" which is what controls whether they should log in or not.

In `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, in an early account line (in my example, the second--after pam_nologin.so), include the following line:

```
account  required     pam_access.so
```

Then in `/etc/security/access.conf` you can put some lines like:

```
+:root:ALL
+:localuser:ALL
+:mygroup:ALL
-:ALL:ALL
```

Which lets users root and "localuser" and anyone in group "mygroup" log in via ssh, but no-one else.  Make sure there isn't a user named "mygroup" or your mileage may vary (there are ways to work around the problem).  Pro tip: make sure you always leave a way to log in and become root that doesn't depend on LDAP, and test all of this prior adding the `-:ALL:ALL` rule and don't leave your root shell until you have proved that everything is working the way you want. You do not need to reboot or otherwise reload any configuration files to activate the new configuration.  Any new ssh attempt will use the new access policy.

Also note, `/etc/security/access.conf` might restrict logins other than ssh--sometimes it is used to restrict the (console) `login` and/or other places where `pam_access.so` might be referenced--so double check all access mechanisms prior to declaring victory.  The last argument in each line controls where the user(s) referenced can come from.